# restful- java private vs public

Tags: java, rest

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Activity {
    private String description;
    private int duration;
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public int getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }
    public void setDuration(int duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }
```

This is code works properly. but when change 3rd and forth lines to public

```
public String description;
public int duration;
```

I get Error 500. I do not understand what is wrong with `public` member type. Every object can access `public` member type. please also explain when to use `public` or `private` ?

Comment: What is the point of having getter and setting methods if you make the field public? When you make it public, the system sees two values of the same name, the field and the property (get/set). Remove the get/set methods, or keep the field private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 500 is not the real error. Look at your logs and you'll likely see the real error.

Here is an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example):

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext.newInstance(Activity.class);
    }
}
@XmlRootElement
class Activity {
    public String description;
    public int duration;
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public int getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }
    public void setDuration(int duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }
}
```

Running it give this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Class has two properties of the same name "description"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String Activity.getDescription()
        at Activity
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String Activity.description
        at Activity
Class has two properties of the same name "duration"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public int Activity.getDuration()
        at Activity
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public int Activity.duration
        at Activity

    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:91)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:445)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:277)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:124)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1123)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:147)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:247)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:234)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:462)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:641)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:584)
    at Test.main(Test.java:7)
```

As you can see, making the field `public` means that JAXB sees two properties of the same name, one defined by the `public` field, and one define by the `get`/`set` bean methods.

Since it doesn't make any sense to have getter and setter methods if you make the field `public`, remove the methods if you want the fields to be `public`.

I'd suggest not making them `public`. Why would you? There is not need, when you have the getter and setter methods for accessing the field.